# How to access an event handler from one class to another class as3

Tags: actionscript-3, class, events

Is it possible to access an event handler from one class to another and if so how? I want to remove an event handler from an object. I have two objects say objectA and objectB. Inside objectA how can I remove an event handler for objectB. This is what I tried but it does not work.

```
MovieClip(root).objectB.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ready);
```

**Details:**

I have two classes called Guest and Guest2. I wanted to know is it possible to remove an eventlistener in the Guest class from Guest2 class. Below is the full code. Note: Both class have exactly the same code

```
package 
        {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
        import flash.events.Event;
        import flash.events.MouseEvent;
        import flash.filters.*;

        public class Guest extends MovieClip
        {
            var walkSpeed:Number = 5;
            var oldPosX;
            var oldPosY;

            var myGlow:GlowFilter = new GlowFilter();

            public function Guest()
            {   
                addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, addGlow);
            }

            function addGlow(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                filters = [myGlow];
                addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, removeGlow);
                addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ready);

            }

            function removeGlow(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                filters = [];
            }

            function ready(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                filters = [myGlow];
                stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, walk);
                removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, removeGlow);
                **MovieClip(root).Guest02.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, walkTo);**
            }

            function walk(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                oldPosX = parent.mouseX;
                oldPosY = parent.mouseY;
                rotation = Math.atan2(oldPosY - y,oldPosX - x) / Math.PI * 180;
                filters = [];
                stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, walk);
                stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
            }

            function loop(event:Event):void
            {
                var dx:Number = oldPosX - x;
                var dy:Number = oldPosY - y;
                var distance:Number = Math.sqrt((dx*dx)+(dy*dy));
                if (distance<walkSpeed)
                {
                    // if you are near the target, snap to it
                    x = oldPosX;
                    y = oldPosY;
                    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);

                }
                else
                {
                    x = x+Math.cos(rotation/180*Math.PI)*walkSpeed;
                    y = y+Math.sin(rotation/180*Math.PI)*walkSpeed;
                }

            }

            **function walkTo(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                _Guest02.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ready);
            }**

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From within objectA you should be able to write:

```
objectB.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ready);
```

The issue you are having it would seem is that you can't get a reference to objectB. I'm guessing that because of the way you are trying to use "root" to get a reference. I would suggest passing a reference to objectB in the constructor of objectA.

```
private var _objectB : ObjectB;

public class ObjectA( objectBRef : ObjectB )
{
    _objectB = objectBRef;
}
```

And then when needed do:

```
_objectB.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ready);
```

Post more code if you are still lost. The entire objectA and objectB classes would be helpful.

**Edit:**

After seeing your new details, I think your approach to how guests are created and managed needs to be re-thought. Having two classes with identical code is generally a bad idea. It seems to me that something outside the guest class should be handling the adding and removing of event handlers, the thing that creates the guests is probably a good place to start.

Comment: it's not working, below is the full code. Let me explain in details. I have two guest. Guest and Guest2. Inside Guest is where I want to remove the event listener of Guest 2. Both Guest and Guest2 class have the exact same code. I will post twice as it is too long.

Comment: I posted up a new question as i can't seem to post my entire code here, can you check that out pls, it has more details of what i want to achieve

Comment: I moved your new details to this question and updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Note**

> No Two classes should ever have exact same code!

It totally fails the purpose of classes & objects.

Anyways, If the code does differ, Do give an effort in implementing inheritance in your code.

---

**Answer**

Add a function to the class & call it, to make it remove it's own listener. Something like :

```
public function removeListeners () {

    this.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ready);
}
```

And call it as :

```
objectB.removeListeners();
```